# How to create a subscription to a user calendar using application permissions to get notifications of all shared,delegated calenders

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

If i have *Calendars.Read* ***application permission*** for events in user calenders, how do i create a subscription to a user calendar using graph api.

below i tried to create event subscription for 'user@mydomain.com' mailbox by updating resource parameter to 'users/user@mydomain.com/events' and is this the right way to subscribe get notifications of shared,delegated calendars of user?

```
{
   "changeType": "created,updated",
   "resource": "users/user@mydomain.com/events",
   "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient",   
   "expirationDateTime":"2016-11-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "secretClientValue"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

(Clarification: I have never created a notification for a resource of this type).

You did not state what the error was.

In your resource field it might need to be:
/users/{userId}/events

The {userId} should not be a UPN but the UUID of the user.

```
{
   "changeType": "created,updated",
   "resource": "users/{userId}/events",
   "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/myNotifyClient",   
   "expirationDateTime":"2016-11-20T18:23:45.9356913Z",
   "clientState": "secretClientValue"
}
```

Comment: is this guarantee  to notify any changes in  user calendars( `/users/{id}/calendars`) ?

Comment: It should (unless documentation states otherwise). However, I have encountered cases in other "graph APIs" that it would not report all action types unless a special undocumented flag was added. But I have never worked with the calendar API, so it may be okay. I always recommend to apply all actions you're interested in and test what works and what doesn't. Just remember that delta API is a "delta" (e.g. if you rename a file 10 times, only the last rename may show).